# How to pass data for an Entry to a listview?

Tags: listview, xamarin, cross-platform

I am building a GroceryListView application in Xamarin CrossPlatform, I am pretty new with this and can't find the way to pass the value for an entry and update my Items listview.

In my **AddItem.cs**

```
Add1=NameEntry.Text;
Add2=CountEntry.Text;
layoutListView1.newItem(Name,Count)

new layoutListView1=layoutListView1;
```

In my AddItem.xaml

With this code is not passing any value to my listview. One more hint my add page is different than my Itemspage(where is my listView)…

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANY HELP

Comment: Are you missing the excerpt from AddItem.xaml in your question?

Comment: I would suggest you show me how you are coming up with a `ListView` with its code behind so i can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the list is on MainPage, and the Entrys are on page1.

Then you can try the following code:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Text="Add Item" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

page1.xaml:

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Entry Text="new name" x:Name="NameEntry"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Entry Text="new count" x:Name="CountEntry"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="Add" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xamal.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyListView.ItemsSource = employees;
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Employee>(this, "add_click", (sender, arg) => {
                employees.Add(arg);
            });
        }

        async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new page1());
        }
    }
```

page1.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Name = NameEntry.Text;
            employee.Count = CountEntry.Text;
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Employee>(this, "add_click", employee);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

You can get the demo on [github](https://github.com/lemontreexf123/teststackoverflow55349741).

Comment: Thank you so much, It work for me. I appreciate your help

Comment: Glad it helps! I would really appreciate it if you will mark my answer.